# How to access more than 50 LogStreams from AWS WatchCloud with 'DescribeLogStreamsRequest'

Tags: java, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I want to access multiple log streams of a log group from cloud watch via java:

```
AWSLogs logsClient = builder.withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                    .withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1)
                    .withClientConfiguration(clientConfig).build();
DescribeLogStreamsRequest describeLogStreamsRequest = new DescribeLogStreamsRequest().withLogGroupName("foo").withOrderBy(OrderBy.LastEventTime).withDescending(true);DescribeLogStreamsResult describeLogStreamsResult = logsClient.describeLogStreams(describeLogStreamsRequest);

 for (LogStream logStream : describeLogStreamsResult.getLogStreams()) {


                GetLogEventsRequest getLogEventsRequest = new GetLogEventsRequest()
                        .withStartTime(startTimestamp)
                        .withEndTime(endTimestamp)
                        .withLogGroupName("fooo")
                        .withLogStreamName(logStream.getLogStreamName());
```

the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeLogStreams.html)  states, that 50 log streams is the max.
Is there any way to access more than the (latest) 50 log streams?

Comment: As you can see in the documentation you provided, there's a `nextToken`. That's part of every AWS API call that gives a list of elements. You need to create a loop and pass the `nextToken` so you can get more elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comment:

> As you can see in the documentation you provided, there's a nextToken. That's part of every AWS API call that gives a list of elements. You need to create a loop and pass the nextToken so you can get more elements

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).